# How do I install Backbonejs in web forms appliction?

Tags: backbone.js

I have included the following scripts in my web application. But I get the error Backbone is undefined when I browse the page.

```
<script src="Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/backbone.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/index.js"></script>
```

What is the problem?

Comment: How on earth could we figure it out from that?

Comment: How do I install the backbonejs in my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error “Backbone is undefined” suggests that somewhere in the JavaScript on the page, you’ve attempted to access the global variable `Backbone` before it’s defined.

Presumably, index.js is the file that contains the JavaScript you‘ve written, and contains the references to `Backbone`. As it’s included on the page after backbone.js, `Backbone` should be defined.

[The Backbone documentation](http://backbonejs.org/) does describe underscore.js as a “hard dependency”, and [the example application there](http://backbonejs.org/examples/todos/index.html) includes underscore.js *before* backbone.js. So maybe it’ll work if you reverse the order of underscore.js and backbone.js:

```
<script src="Scripts/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/backbone.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hooray! Glad to hear it. They should make that clearer in the Backbone documentation really. Although I think you should have seen an error in your console from Backbone complaining about `_` not being defined.